# Deferred call to sync.WaitGroup.Wait() in Goroutine: why should this work?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I'm trying to understand the `Attack()` function (https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta/blob/44a49c878dd6f28f04b9b5ce5751490b0dce1e18/lib/attack.go#L253-L312) in the source code of the `vegeta` load testing tool/library. I've created a simplified example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go attack(&wg)
    }
    // wg.Wait()

    go func() {
        defer wg.Wait()
    }()
}

func attack(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("foobar")
}
```

What I notice is that this function returns immediately without printing `foobar` 10 times. It is only if comment in the line `wg.Wait()` that I see `foobar` printed 10 times after 1 second. This makes sense to me, because the `main()` function returns before `wg.Wait()` is called.

What I don't understand, then, is how the `Attack()` method works in `vegeta`, because it seems to follow a similar pattern:

```
func (a *Attacker) Attack(tr Targeter, p Pacer, du time.Duration, name string) <-chan *Result {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    workers := a.workers
    if workers > a.maxWorkers {
        workers = a.maxWorkers
    }

    results := make(chan *Result)
    ticks := make(chan struct{})
    for i := uint64(0); i < workers; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go a.attack(tr, name, &wg, ticks, results)
    }

    go func() {
        defer close(results)
        defer wg.Wait()
        defer close(ticks)

        began, count := time.Now(), uint64(0)
        for {
            elapsed := time.Since(began)
            if du > 0 && elapsed > du {
                return
            }

            wait, stop := p.Pace(elapsed, count)
            if stop {
                return
            }

            time.Sleep(wait)

            if workers < a.maxWorkers {
                select {
                case ticks <- struct{}{}:
                    count++
                    continue
                case <-a.stopch:
                    return
                default:
                    // all workers are blocked. start one more and try again
                    workers++
                    wg.Add(1)
                    go a.attack(tr, name, &wg, ticks, results)
                }
            }

            select {
            case ticks <- struct{}{}:
                count++
            case <-a.stopch:
                return
            }
        }
    }()

    return results
}
```

where the `attack()` method reads

```
func (a *Attacker) attack(tr Targeter, name string, workers *sync.WaitGroup, ticks <-chan struct{}, results chan<- *Result) {
    defer workers.Done()
    for range ticks {
        results <- a.hit(tr, name)
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the `Attack()` function doesn't return immediately without invoking `attack()`, since its `wg.Wait()` is inside a Goroutine?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't return immediately?

Comment: When main returns the program and all goroutines terminate. When Attack returns goroutines continue working.

Comment: Is the code that invokes Attack(..) reading from the returned 'results' channel ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vegeta's `Attack` also immediately returns, but with a channel which is populated by the goroutines that remain running.
Once those finish the channel is closed (`defer close(results)`) enabling code that has `result` to detect completion.

Example;

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    results := attacks()

    fmt.Println("attacks returned")

    for result := range results {
        fmt.Println(result)
    }
}

func attacks() chan string {
    // A channel to hold the results
    c := make(chan string)

    // Fire 10 routines populating the channel
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            attack(c)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }

    // Close channel once routines are finished
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(c)
    }()

    //
    return c
}

func attack(c chan<- string) {
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    c <- "foobar"
}
```